# Identify new number in unordered stream

Tags: math, data-structures, numbers, numerical-methods

I am getting an unordered  stream of numbers. Is there a data structure that I can hold in order to know if a number already exist in the stream without holding a collection of the numbers that I got from the stream  ( it is infinite stream) ?

Comment: Is it an infinite stream of numbers from a finite range or set? E.g. a stream of only 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: Actually it is stream of hashcodes so it  is very wide range

Comment: And it would of course be typical for hashes not to have any useful relationship like e.g. monotonously ascending...

Comment: For `n`-bit hash codes you might want a `2^n` bit bitmap.  When you read a code, test the corresponding bit, if you've not already seen it set that bit.  Finding a location in a bitmap is about `O(1)`.

Comment: And if a 2^n bit bitmap is too much memory, you might be able to use a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). Although you there is a potential for false positives.

Comment: You can't significantly compress random data. If there is some nonrandomness to the numbers you could exploit this, otherwise you are essentially out of luck (which isn't to deny that some data structures might be better than others for the intended application).

Comment: @igx: is it indiscreet to ask you the code lengths ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it is literally a stream of numbers. I was just wondering if there is some kind of metadata / calculations that I can save on the stream that will let me know if the number is new. if yes then update the calculations. – igx 9 secs ago   edit

Comment: @Yunnosch I do not need to keep the data stream so I thought that compressing might be redundant.

Comment: If you want to keep information for yourself, don't expect good answers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't understand what do you mean. I am getting a stream of numbers which I need to know if is new number, if yes than I need to process it otherwise I can ignore it. simple as that.

Comment: You don't even want to tell the code length.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think I get you. what do you mean code length ? you mean the length of the stream ? it is infinite

Comment: Of course not, I know the stream is infinite. n.

Comment: He's asking how large the codes are. Are they 16 bit integers? 32 bit integers? What is the smallest and largest possible code?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry for the misunderstanding it is 32 bit (int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to avoid holding all the previously seen numbers.

For this purpose, a hash table is probably the most appropriate.

It could be that (marginal) savings are possible by compression or by taking advantage of some property of the data, but you haven't told us much about it.

Comment: it is literally a stream of numbers. I was just wondering if there is some kind of metadata / calculations that I can save on the stream that will let me know if the number is new. if yes then update the calculations

Answer (score 1):

Create a bit stream, when you see a number goto that bit and flip it. In this way you can remember numbers using less space.

So if numbers to be remembered are 32 bit long. Total space required to store bit stream would be 2^32 bits or 536.870912 megabytes and a constant time to access the bit stream.

If the numbers are large, you can hash them again to 32 bits.

Comment: it's not what I was looking for because it consumes a lot of memory even might be more than it should (e.g if I have 4 repeated numbers). but it is a good solution +1